# Setting executor environment variables in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, environment-variables, hadoop-yarn, amazon-data-pipeline

I am using spark-defaults classification [http://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-spark-configure.html] and providing the following property:- `spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.FOO = "foo"` to set environment variables in the yarn master.

I wanted to know if these variables will be present in the executor instances as well? If not, is there a way to do the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Environment variables set by property spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.FOO = "foo" won't be present on executor instances.

I use the below Classification to set-up environment variables on executor and master node:

```
[   
  {
   "Classification": "yarn-env",
   "Properties": {},
   "Configurations": [
       {
         "Classification": "export",
         "Properties": {
             "VARIABLE_NAME": VARIABLE_VALUE,
         }
       }
   ]
 }
]
```

Comment: Thanks. Worked like a charm